# While loop not exiting when False

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with input validation using a != in my math game. My while loop is evaluating as False, but it's not exiting the loop like I expect to. It just gets stuck in the loop any won't exit with any input.

```
 import random

numCorrect = 0
operand1 = 0
operand2 = 0
operator = 0
correctAnswer = 0
userInput = 0
playAgain = "Y"


print("Welcome to the Looping Math Game!\nAnswer these questions, and get 5 correct to win.")


while playAgain == "Y":
    while numCorrect != 1:
        operand1 = random.randint(1,10)
        operand2 = random.randint(1,10)
        operator = random.randint(1,3)
      if operator == 1:
         correctAnswer = operand1 * operand2
         userInput = int(input("{} * {} = ".format(operand1, operand2)))
         if userInput == correctAnswer:
            print("Correct!")
            numCorrect +=1

         else:
            print("Incorrect...")

      if operator == 2:
         correctAnswer = operand1 + operand2
         userInput = int(input("{} + {} = ".format(operand1, operand2)))
         if userInput == correctAnswer:
            print("Correct!")
            numCorrect +=1

         else:
            print("Incorrect...")

      if operator == 3:
         correctAnswer = operand1 - operand2
         userInput = int(input("{} - {} = ".format(operand1, operand2)))
         if userInput == correctAnswer:
            print("Correct!")
            numCorrect +=1

        else:
            print("Incorrect...")

    print("You win!")
    playAgain = input("Would you like to play again? (Y/N): ")
    while playAgain != "Y" or playAgain !="N":
       print("Invalid input. Try again!")
       playAgain = input("Would you like to play again? (Y/N): ")
```

Comment: Did you used a `return` or `break` statement ?

Comment: you need to edit the code.. the indentation is broken

Comment: There is nothing inside the loop to get it to exit.  There is no `break`, and you never alter the value of the loop control variable.  How do you think it's going to stop?  Did you not trace the execution?

Comment: I think I fixed the indentation. It broke copying in the code. I think my understanding is incomplete, but why do I need a break statement. My understanding is that if the while evaluates False it would exit the loop. Where would I place the break statement? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually pretty close to functional.  I decided to pop it into my IDE just to see how many fixes were required.  Here are some notes I made from doing that:

- `while numCorrect != 1:` is an infinite loop, since none of the code inside it will change the value of `numCorrect`.  I could tell what you were trying to do there.
- You need a second loop to keep asking questions until the user gets 5 right, so we do need that `while` loop...it just needs to be moved out a level.
- The code at the bottom needs to be inside the outer loop so that if the user wants to play again, the code flow can go back to the start (UPDATE: looks like you fixed that)
- The line `while playAgain != "Y" or playAgain !="N":` is another infinite loop.  Think about it.  A letter can't be two things at once, so it's always going to either not be "Y" or not be "N".  You simply want `and` here rather than `or`.

Here's my version, which seems to work well:

```
import random

numCorrect = 0
operand1 = 0
operand2 = 0
operator = 0
correctAnswer = 0
userInput = 0
playAgain = "Y"

correctToWin = 5

print("Welcome to the Looping Math Game!\nAnswer these questions, and get {} correct to win.".format(correctToWin))


while playAgain == "Y":

    numCorrect = 0

    while numCorrect < correctToWin:
        operand1 = random.randint(1,10)
        operand2 = random.randint(1,10)
        operator = random.randint(1,3)

        if operator == 1:
            correctAnswer = operand1 * operand2
            userInput = int(input("{} * {} = ".format(operand1, operand2)))
            if userInput == correctAnswer:
                print("Correct!")
                numCorrect +=1

            else:
                print("Incorrect...")

        if operator == 2:
            correctAnswer = operand1 + operand2
            userInput = int(input("{} + {} = ".format(operand1, operand2)))
            if userInput == correctAnswer:
                print("Correct!")
                numCorrect +=1

            else:
                print("Incorrect...")

        if operator == 3:
            correctAnswer = operand1 - operand2
            userInput = int(input("{} - {} = ".format(operand1, operand2)))
            if userInput == correctAnswer:
                print("Correct!")
                numCorrect +=1

            else:
                print("Incorrect...")

    print("You win!")
    playAgain = input("Would you like to play again? (Y/N): ")
    while playAgain != "Y" and playAgain !="N":
        print("Invalid input. Try again!")
        playAgain = input("Would you like to play again? (Y/N): ")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining the infinite loop that was the main problem I was having. Also sorry everyone for the other issues that made diagnosing the problem difficult.